# MySQL won't run XAMPP MacOs Catalina

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mariadb, xampp

I have a problem. Namely XAMPP does not start MySQL. I have tried several methods, including:

First try (executed in terminal):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

response:

```
Starting MariaDB
.2022-05-30 16:40:40 6012 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mateuszs-macbook-pro.home.err'.
2022-05-30 16:40:40 6012 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
./Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (6012) - No such process
 ERROR!
```

Second try (executed in terminal):

```
sudo killall mysqld
```

response:

```
No matching processes were found
```

I have also changed port in my.cnf (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc) to 3308 in both [mysqld] and [client], it didn't help.

I checked file xampp (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles) and in function startMySQL there was already a line in the file, the addition of which could be a solution.

```
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When i started mysql manually (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin) the respons was:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

And as far as I am concerned it means that MySQL is not running.

Specs:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- XAMPP (regular, not XAMPP-VM) version 8.1.5-0

I have looked for solutions on Google, YouTube and StackOverflow, but none that I have found have solved my problem. I will point out that I installed XAMPP maybe 2 weeks ago.
**Edit:** When i execute mysqladmin shutdown in terminal the response is:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Comment: Question updated :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to XAMPP manager, and selected "Manage Servers". I selected the "Configure" option for the MySQL database and changed the port from 3306 to 3308. It worked!